# Accessing media files using Scoped Storage on Android 10 or higher

Tags: java, android, scoped-storage

I want to access the media files/ videos from the shared storage using Media Store on Android >=10.
I read the google developer documentation but didn't get the answer( https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media ).
I want to access videos from the shared storage using MediaStore.Video.

I tried the following code but it didn't work, even the menu to selection menu was not opened :

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    List<Video> videoList = new ArrayList<Video>(); //Video is a class.
    Uri collection;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        //Media Store
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
        } else {
            collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
 
        }
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE
        };
        String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION +
                " >= ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
        };

        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
        try (Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                collection,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                sortOrder)) {
            // Cache column indices.
            int idColumn = ((Cursor) cursor).getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
            int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int durationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
            int sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);
 
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Get values of columns for a given video.
                long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
                int duration = cursor.getInt(durationColumn);
                int size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn);
 
                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
 
                // Stores column values and the contentUri in a local object
                // that represents the media file.
                videoList.add(new Video(contentUri, name, duration, size));
            }
        }
    }
}
 
 
//Video Class
public class Video {
    private final Uri uri;
    private final String name;
    private final int duration;
    private final int size;
 
    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
 
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
 
    public Video(Uri uri, String name, int duration, int size) {
        this.uri = uri;
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.size = size; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `want to access the media files/ videos from the shared storage using Media Store` Ok. But then put that in the subject of your post too.

Comment: Check if it returns any video without adding any filters, pass null for `selection` and `selectionArgs` and see.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with you code, But you haven't asked for External storage read permission.

Add following permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ....
</manifest>
```

And ask for this permission at run time like shown in [Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Comment: And display it somewhere or log it so you can easily find it out whether it's working or not. else you have to debug your code with breakpoints to find it out.